# Не могу найти ошибку в SQL запросе!

Tags: mysql, sql

Из двух таблиц courses и purchaselist, запрос должен вернуть таблицу из двух столбцов.
Надо написать запрос, который выводит сумму, сколько часов должен в итоге проучиться каждый студент (сумма длительности всех курсов на которые он подписан).
В результате запрос возвращает две колонки: Имя Студента — Количество часов.

Таблица courses

| name | duration |
| --- | --- |
| Мобильный разработчик с нуля | 10 |
| Веб-разработчик c 0 до PRO | 10 |
| Python-разработчик с нуля | 4 |
| PHP-разработчик с 0 до PRO | 3 |
| Java-разработчик | 5 |

Таблица purchaselist

| student_name | course_name |
| --- | --- |
| Амбражевич Порфирий | Мобильный разработчик |
| Жариков Афанасий | Мобильный разработчик |
| Бойков Максим | Мобильный разработчик |
| Гайденко Илья | Мобильный разработчик |
| Ядрихинский Егор | Java-разработчик |
| Амбражевич Порфирий | Java-разработчик |
| Жариков Афанасий | Java-разработчик |
| Бойков Максим | Python-разработчик |
| Гайденко Илья | Python-разработчик |
| Ядрихинский Егор | Python-разработчик |
| Амбражевич Порфирий | Python-разработчик |
| Жариков Афанасий | Веб-разработчик |
| Бойков Максим | PHP-разработчик |
| Гайденко Илья | PHP-разработчик |
| Ядрихинский Егор | PHP-разработчик |

Я написал следующий запрос:

```
SELECT student_name AS "Имя Студента", SUM(duration) AS "Количество часов"
FROM (SELECT student_name, course_name AS name, duration FROM purchaselist, courses) AS s;
```

Вместо таблицы выводится одна строка!

Comment: Вам годится узнать про JOIN

Comment: Каждый студент подписан только на один курс?

Comment: Fabio Mendes Soares
 Да, годится.

Comment: Anton Shchyrov  Это только часть таблиц.

Comment: Чисто из интереса, как Вы собираетесь доставать информацию о курсе, если `name` и `course_name` вообще разные...

Comment: Если это только часть таблиц, то как мы должны вам помочь? [mcve]

Comment: *Вместо таблицы выводится одна строка!* - естественно, Вы не группируете по студентам.  Для начала уточните свою версию БД

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SQL**

```
SELECT
   P.student_name,
   SUM(C.duration)
FROM purchaselist P
JOIN courses C ON C.name = P.course_name
--JOIN courses C ON C.name LIKE P.course_name
GROUP BY P.student_name
```

Тут уже от Вашей задачи зависит, по данным не понятно. Либо курсы равны названиям, либо содержат.

Comment: Спасибо, всё понятно и пояснения тоже в тему!!!